# To show that differential equation $\lvert{dy\over{dx}}\rvert\,+\mid{y}\mid+1=0 $ has no real solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given differential equation
$$\lvert{dy\over{dx}}\rvert\,+\mid{y}\mid+1=0 $$

I don't know how to deal with modulus sign in order to prove the statement

Reference-Different Equations by Shipley L Ross Ch1 Exercise 7(a)

Comment: Absolute value sign but yeah same difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $|a|+|b|$ cannot be less than $0$ for reals $a$ and $b$.